Unpredictable Emacs echo area flashing on new message
Unpredictible Emacs echo area flashing on new message
I am using my own fork of emacs-mini-modeline. It's a package that displays text message and modeline content in the echo area, to save space obviously, since the echo area is empty most of the time. The code is at https://github.com/QiangF/emacs-mini-modeline
I have fixed most of the issues for that package. The last one is the flashing of the mini-modeline during text editing in mode other than "fundamental mode". I have a screencast of the flashing for org-mode.
The file for the screencast is https://github.com/QiangF/emacs-mini-modeline/blob/master/flashing_on_editing_org_mode_buffer.webm
The screencast is recorded with “emacs -Q” and the loaded packages are dash.el and mini-modeline.el
Steps to reproduce:

emacs -Q -l dash.el
open mini-modeline.el and evaluate the buffer
enable mini-modeline-mode
open a buffer and enable prog-mode or org-mode
start tying some lines and heading, you will see the fliker in the echo area

Once that is solved, use the echo area to display information will be quite pleasant
Make use of an empty echo area to display information
The screencast can also be viewed here https://webm.red/view/fOrF.webm
There is no flicker in text-mode, see
https://webmshare.com/play/eGNWR

As always, do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with emacs -Q (no init file)? If not, then bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, then show a step-by-step recipe, starting from emacs -Q, to repro the problem. Otherwise your question isn't clear.

I have added the steps. I need someone more knowledgeable in Emacs internals to tell what is causing the refreshing of the echo area during text editing.
